# How to block hidden pop-unders despite having adblockers?

Tags: adblock

one great example is rapidgator. when clicking the text box to solve captcha, it triggers a pop-under/up. While poper blocker blocks this in Chrome, there are many other instances where it got passed.

What is the best way to protect against such intrusive ads?

I already have adblock (with all major lists subscribed), ublock origin, poper blocker installed.

Comment: Just a quick comment, avoiding these might be a bit difficult. At least some popunders are created by exploiting how a given browser fundamentally works, even if the browser itself or relevant ad blockers are designed to block other techniques. Much like blocking regular exploits, some of these basic interactions can't be blocked until the browser behavior itself is changed/patched (or perhaps a plug in is updated to account for the behavior somehow).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ghostery?

Other than blocking ads, it blocks the trackers themselves, in order to completely remove the functionality of the ad from the page.(Similar to ublock origin)

If that doesn't work, It is best to use the block an ad feature in Adblock, which allows you to block that specific popup on the page, after right-clicking on it.